# Best itinerary for a three week trip in the Balkans?

Tags: balkans

Me and my boyfriend are visiting the Balkans on 25th June. We only have three weeks so most likely can't do all of this so if there's any you think we should cut off(or add on) let me know! Although we are keen on doing quite a few day trips so please suggest if there would be a good base for us to go on day trips from in certain countries. We're flying into Serbia, and ending in Slovenia as we will be going over to Berlin after. Anyway here's what I've got...

SERBIA 
Belgrade

MONTENEGRO 
Budva 
Kotor

CROATIA 
Dubrovnik 
Zagreb

BOSNIA 
Mostar 
Neum 
Sarajevo

SLOVENIA 
Ljubljana 
Bled

Comment: This question is off-topic here, but I would recommend visiting the poorest countries first: Albania, Kosovo, Macedonia.

Comment: Welcome to TSE! Please have a look on what questions are on-topic here. Yours is going to get closed as off-topic since we don't construct itineraries, it is too broad and primarily opinion-based.